# I am trying to use the database for store and display function

Tags: android

currenly have been using 2 database, one database for log in and sign up another for displaying of information

```
public class huh extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "exerbud.db";
    private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 1;
    Context c;
    public huh(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
        c=context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE hmm ( _id INTERGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +   //error
                " namestr TEXT, emailstr TEXT, phonestr TEXT, gender_type TEXT);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //Will not be called until SCHEMA_VERSION increases
        //Here we can upgrade the database e.g. add more tables
    }

    public Cursor getAll() {
        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
                "SELECT _id, namestr, emailstr, phonestr," +
                        " gender_type FROM hmm ORDER BY namestr", null));
    }

    public void insert (String namestr, String emailstr, String phonestr, String gender_type) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        Toast.makeText(c,"In huh Insert",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        cv.put("namestr", namestr);
        cv.put("phonestr",phonestr );
        cv.put("emailstr",emailstr );
        cv.put("gender_type",gender_type );

        SQLiteDatabase dbt= getWritableDatabase(); //error
        if(dbt!=null) {

            Toast.makeText(c,"writeable database is not null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            /*getWritableDatabase().insert("hmm", "namestr", cv);*/
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(c,"writeable database is null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    public String getName(Cursor c) {
        return (c.getString(1));
    }

    public String getEmail(Cursor c) {
        return (c.getString(2));
    }

    public String getTel(Cursor c) {
        return (c.getString(3));
    }

    public String getGenderType(Cursor c) {
        return (c.getString(4));
    }
}
```

the database name is called "huh"
As seen in the code the lines that have error in them are marks with //error.
I was also trying out if database was null but it wasn't null

**update{1}:**

after @ewong suggestion I have changed the word INTERGER to INTEGER which fixes the database error, however it doesn't display the display page

here is the current progress for far
[edit profile /insert profile page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7EUS.png)
[following output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmfqY.png)

which is correct however, this should be the correct output: [correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFtlH.png)

I am currently basing off of previous database.

**update{2}:**

i already have updated the code in the following code below:

```
public class huh extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "exerbud.db";
    private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 1;
    Context c;
    public huh(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
        c=context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE hmm ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +   //error
                " namestr TEXT, emailstr TEXT, phonestr TEXT, gender_type TEXT);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //Will not be called until SCHEMA_VERSION increases
        //Here we can upgrade the database e.g. add more tables
    }

    public Cursor getAll() {
        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
                "SELECT _id, namestr, emailstr, phonestr," +
                        " gender_type FROM hmm ORDER BY namestr", null));
    }

    public void insert (String namestr, String emailstr, String phonestr, String gender_type) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        Toast.makeText(c,"In huh Insert",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        cv.put("namestr", namestr);
        cv.put("phonestr",phonestr );
        cv.put("emailstr",emailstr );
        cv.put("gender_type",gender_type );
        getWritableDatabase().insert("hmm", "namestr", cv);
        /*
        //SQLiteDatabase dbt= getWritableDatabase(); //error
        if(dbt!=null) {

            Toast.makeText(c,"writeable database is not null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(c,"writeable database is null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }*/
    }

    public String getName(Cursor c) {
        return (c.getString(1));
    }

    public String getEmail(Cursor c) {
        return (c.getString(2));
    }

    public String getTel(Cursor c) {
        return (c.getString(3));
    }

    public String getGenderType(Cursor c) {
        return (c.getString(4));
    }
}
```

it doesn't display the display page
this should be the correct output: [correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFtlH.png)
but i got this output: [wrong output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7EUS.png), [wrong output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmfqY.png)

update{3}:
no errors in logcat
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juOzc.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  "```INTERGER```"?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice   /*getWritableDatabase().insert("hmm", "namestr", cv);* unidenfied error here and table creation error

Comment: @ewong          sorry still new to coding i modified codes from my previous project not sure if it's supposed to be there

Comment: I think providing the error message would help us a lot, knowing on which line the app breaks doesn't always mean the error is related to only that line

Comment: Start by fixing the spellin that ewong mentioned above. If your app still doesn't work you will need to look at logcat to find the full error message.

Comment: @JustSightseeing I have updated my question to clear any confusion

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I posted an update but still encounter more problem in displaying of information

Comment: @WutsDatDebuff Spelling still not fixed. Read the first comment.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i have updated thw spelling in update{2} but still the same problem

Comment: Check the logcat to see if there are any other errors. Then use the Android Studio debugger to debug your code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice after looking thru the logcat there isn't any errors

Comment: Next use the debugger to step through your app to figure out what's going on .